# Calendar, check if there is events before "a given" date

Tags: android, date, android-calendar

I have an interface in my app that loads the events of the Android Calendar from a given date range.

[image]

The *"Back in date"* Button, allows the user to navigate by **one** month in the past ( to get events since that date).

This is my code to get events between two dates:

```
private List<CalendarEvent> getEventsFromCalendar(Date dateSince, Date dateUntil) {
    try {
        ArrayList<CalendarEvent> list = new ArrayList<CalendarEvent>();
        String[] projections = { CalendarContract.Events._ID, CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART};
        String cond = CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART+" >= "+dateSince.getTime();
        if(dateUntil != null){
            cond += " AND "+CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART+" < "+dateUntil.getTime();
        }
        Cursor c = this.getActivity().getContentResolver().query(Constants.CALENDAR_EVENTS_URI, projections, cond, null, CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART);
        if(c!=null){
            while (c.moveToNext()) {
                int id = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(CalendarContract.Events._ID));
                String title = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(CalendarContract.Events.TITLE));
                Date start = new Date(c.getLong(c.getColumnIndex(CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART)));
                CalendarEvent event = new CalendarEvent(id, title, start);
                list.add(event);
            }
            c.close();

        }
        return list;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error(e.getMessage());
        return new ArrayList<>();
    }
}
```

**My problem:**

I want to disable the *"Back in date"* Button when there is no events in the past (no other events before `dateSince` ).

**My first thought:**

Everytime i call  `getEventsFromCalendar()` method, i make **another** `query` with condition `CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART+" < "+dateSince.getTime();` to check if there is more events in the past. So if i don't get any result, i disable my Button.

But i don't want to load all the past events, just to check their existence.

**Questions:**

- Is there a better solution to check if there is events in the `Calendar` before a given date (in other words, events starts before a given date)?
- Is it possible to get events by group from the `Calendar`?

eg: get the first 10 events (from 1st to 11th), then the next 10 (from 12th to 21th)...

Thanks in advance!